# WPF - Black screen instead of screenshot

Tags: wpf, screen-scraping, screenshot

I use the following code to get screenshot:

```
    public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource()
    {
        using (var screenBmp = new Bitmap(Convert.ToInt32(System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth), 
            Convert.ToInt32(System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight), 
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
        {
            using (var bmpGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenBmp))
            {
                bmpGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0,
                    0, screenBmp.Size);
                return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(screenBmp.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            }
        }
    }
```

It works fine for normal window, but I get black rectangle on FullScreen app instead of screenshot. Why and how to fix?
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean Window is in Maximize state when you get the Black screenshot ?

Comment: no, I mean FullScreen, like Games

Comment: So isn't that code working for you that I posted in my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is accurate. I think you are having a problem when saving the screenshot. So here I have attached my test result

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PngBitmapEncoder png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(ToBitmapSource()));    // Calling your method
    using (Stream stm = File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "screenshot.png"))
    {
        png.Save(stm);
    }
}
```

[image]